# Find column starting with "Email" VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very limited knowledge of VBA. However, with the help of google I did the script which searches for the column called Email. Then if it finds it it looks if in this column are any commas. If yes, then it changes commas into dots. 
However, this solution is case sensitive. If the column name is slightly different, then it doesn't work. So far I know there are 2 different options which were used in the files which this script will clean
1. Email
2. Email - Personal Email

I would like to be able to make this script to work in all Email starting columns. I tried to specify this as "Email*" but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

```
Sub mySample()
Sheets("Data").Activate
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For Each ws In Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets
i = ws.Cells(1, Excel.Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column

For j = 1 To i
    If ws.Cells(1, j).Value = "Email" Then
        Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
Next j
Next ws
Sheets("Automation").Activate
MsgBox "Removing commas in emails - Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to see this? http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: @SiddharthRout comment worth an answer! yours is much more detailed than mine - I just suggested the idea)

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend you to use different approach: instead of looping trough cells of 1st column - just use **Excel Search** to identify the e-mail column:

```
LookupString = "Email"
Set SearchRange = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find(LookupString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

With the options given you'll find properly ANY `LookupString` value match, regardless of position and case in column name. Replace `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.` part with the names of WB / sheet as required.

Further you may use returned `SearchRange` properties, such as `Column`, for further processing of data in the column. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`InStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function:

```
   If InStr(UCase(ws.Cells(1, j).Value), UCase("Email")) Then
```

`UCase` function converts a string to all upper-case, so your comparison is not case sensitive anymore

Answer (score 1):

As far as making `If ws.Cells(1, j).Value = "Email"` more inclusive, I'd suggest using `InStr` instead. This will search for the string "email" anywhere in the cell, and let you know the position at which it appears. If it's anything other than 0, that means the string was found. (More on `InStr` [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php).)

```
For j = 1 To i
    If Instr(1,ws.Cells(1, j).Value,"email",vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Cells.Replace...
```

The `Cells.Replace...` line looks little weird to me as well. Is that working properly for you?